# Changing HTML onclick event action(different)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am very new to the web development area.  I have some doubts regarding my Web development.  Any one help me please.

**SCENARIO**

I made a button using div tag, this is the CSS code for button I made:

```
#signupbutton
 {
    height: 29px;
    width: 120px;
    background-image: url(../images/onState1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 265px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#signupbutton:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/onState0.png);
}
#signupbutton:active {
    background-image: url(../images/onState10.png);
}
```

And this is the HTML for the button:

```
<div id="signupbutton" onclick="document.forms.signupform.submit()"></div>
```

I need to change the onclick action of this button using jQuery
that is `onclick="document.forms.signupform.submit()"` (need to change this action).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what are you trying to change it to?

Comment: Hi Sam, What are you trying to get it to do?

Comment: @JonTaylor  i trying to change this action to any other action..like some error message or any alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#signupbutton').removeAttr('onclick') // this removes the `onclick` attribute
$('#signupbutton').click(function(){
   $('#signupform').submit();
   // alert('clicked')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="signupbutton"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#signupbutton').click(function() { 
alert('Button Clicked'); //or any action you want here
});
```

Comment: He doesn't actually want it to submit anymore, but for reference you can just replace the `$('#myform').submit();` with any other code you want.

Comment: You basically just refactored his code... I'm pretty sure he's asking how to change the event programatically.

Comment: I believe he doesn't know how to attach a jquery event to the button. It's a bit unclear, I will wait and see his response.